# Get the rel attribute value of all checked inputs as an array or csv using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv, checkbox

I have around 9 checkboxes with different rel values. How can I get the all the rel values of checked check boxes in an array or as csv using jQuery?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item" rel="WVSEUPU" />
```

Comment: input elements don't have a *rel* attribute, either use a standard attribute (e.g. class) or an HTML5 *data-* attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var relArr=[];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
relArr.push($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7zSRQ/

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var rels = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    rels.push(rel);
});
//rels is an array you could use rels.join(',') to join the array.
```

Comment: you beat me to it :) ... P.S i think you will have to add `:checked` as the OP wants the checked values ...

Comment: "checked check boxes", so I would change the first line to `$('input:checked').each(function(){`